# gulp sass not minifying

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

Having a task to process SCSS files (where some of them are just plain CSS) the end result is not minified .. This is part of my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var gutil       = require('gulp-util');
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var concatCss   = require('gulp-concat-css');
var minifyCss   = require('gulp-minify-css');

var estilos = [
    'app/scss/bootstrap.scss', /*a bunch of includes of other scss files*/
    'node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css',
    'node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css',
    'app/scss/estilos.scss',
    'app/scss/indexSlider.scss'
]

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(estilos)
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed' }).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(concatCss('final.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
});
```

I just started 2 days ago with gulp so my debugging skills are pretty minimum so far... what I'm I doing wrong for the final file not being minified?

Comment: why `.pipe(concatCss('final.min.css'))` ? 
Just add this css to the `src`.

Comment: That's the final file name I want outputed. All scss files processed, minified and contcated to that specific file

Comment: but you should import partials in `sass`...

Comment: Don't have a clue on how to do that! Will have to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a different src in your `estilos`, at first you have to compile them each to css, then merge. You can find the answer in this example https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2015/10/22/gulp-merge-less-sass-css/.

Hope is there help you)

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the concat before the minifying:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(estilos)
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed' }).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(concatCss('final.min.css'))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
});
```

that should fix it.

Also I would recommend to use gulp-clean-css because gulp-minify-css has being deprecated.

Comment: I tried that before and got errors when executing the task